# How to change node.js url parameters from id to keywords for a blog

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a blog using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and want to make the blog more search engine friendly.

Currently the show route for one of my posts is `/blogs/:id` with the id being a huge string of numbers. 
I would like it to be `/blogs/title-of-example-post` but I cannot find anything online stating how to do this with javascript.

***Is it possible to write a function that could find a post by id and display its title in the url? Here is my show route code.***

```
app.get("/blogs/:id", function(req, res){
  Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog){
      if(err){
          res.redirect("/blogs");
      } else {
          res.render("show", {blog: foundBlog});
      }
  })
});
```

*Thanks for your help!*

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, of course; you need to look up how to search by fields other than ID in Mongoose.

Answer (score 2):

Normally this is done with something called a slug. It's usually generated at article write time and is unique but based on the article title for, as you mentioned, SEO purposes.

What you'd want to do is store the slug on the Blog document and find by that, instead of the ID. Something like follows:

`Blog.find({ slug: req.params.slug}, function (err, foundBlog) {`

You'll have to generate slugs for all articles that currently exist, but that should be relatively simple to script - normally it's just a matter of lowercasing, removing punctuation, and changing spaces to dashes. If you want to get fancy you can remove trivial words like "the". Here's one example NPM package which transforms strings to slugs out of the box: [slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify)

Run that on all past articles and add code into your blog authoring page to generate it when you save new articles.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am a bit new at this so sorry if I am bothering you with this question. I installed slugify and cannot seem to get my code to slugify the title in the url. Here is what I have. Any more assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I use [mongoose-slug-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-slug-generator) while setting up my Blog Schema with Mongoose. Its has an easy to follow documentation and works out of the box.

A simple set up consists of installing, loading and initializing mongoose-slug-generator plugin:

`npm install mongoose-slug-generator --save`

Or with Yarn

`yarn add mongoose-slug-generator`

###### Now let's create our Blog / Article Mongoose Schema

```
    const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const { Schema } = Mongoose;

    // Load mongoose-slug-generator plugin
    const slug = require('mongoose-slug-generator');

    // mongoose-slug-generator options (Optional)
    const options = {
      separator: '-',
      lang: 'en',
      truncate: 120
    };

    // Initizalize mongoose-slug-generator
    Mongoose.plugin(slug, options);

    //
    // Article Schema
    //
    const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
      slug: {
        type: String,
        slug: 'title', // article slug will be generated from "title"
        unique: true
      },
      image: {
        type: String
      },
      active: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true
      },
      updated: Date,
      created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    });

    module.exports = Mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

As for the GET request, I usually define an utility function to check for a valid mongoose ObjectId, you may find it quite helpful to keep it on a separate folder and then include / require it when you need it.

`/src/utils/validateObject.js`

```
    /**
     * Validate Mongoose ObjectId
     * @params {object} id
     */
    const validateObjectId = (id) => {
        const { Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose;
        return ObjectId.isValid(id) && (new ObjectId(id)).toString() === id;
    };

    module.exports = validateObjectId;
```

`/src/models/blog.js`

```
    const express = require('express');
    const Blog = require('../../models/blog');
    const validateObjectId = require('../../utils/validateObject');

    ...

    app.get("/blogs/:id", async(req, res) => {

      const { id } = req.params;
      const blog = validateObjectId(id) ? Blog.findById(id) : Blog.findOne({ slug: id });

      blog
      .exec((err, foundBlog) => {
        if (err) {
          res.redirect("/blogs");
        }

        if (!foundBlog) {
          res.redirect("/404");
        }

        res.render("show", { blog: foundBlog });
      });
    });
 
    ...
```